# Unable to scroll in Scroll rect with input fields Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, keyboard, input-field, scrollrect

I have a problem which makes me crazy. I have created a `scroll rect` in unity with a lot of `Input Field`'s like in picture below.

[image]

My problem is : **I can't scroll!!!** Every time when I try, the keyboard it's opened. Scroll it's able just if I hit the red space between the `Input field`'s.

I am thinking that the problem is because the keyboard appears on `OnPointerDown` and not `OnPointerUp` or `OnPointerClick`. I tried to add a `EventTrigger` component to `InputField` and add actions for `OnPointerDown` and `OnPointerUp` but I had no success to change keyboard behavior.

Any help? Any ideas? Please! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm i am somewhat certain, that there must be a less hacky way, but i suppose you could create an invisible area/image on top of the input field and track in the event of that area/object/image how far the scrolling was/if any. and if the scrolling was below a certain distance than you can decide "hey this was actually supposed to go to the input field" and call the input field event.. i guess? =)

Answer (score 6):

You can create Button and attach InputField as child of it, then:

1. add button OnClick event `InputField.Select()`
2. Disable `Raycast Target` for InputField, Placeholder and Text

To hide button you can make it transparent.

Comment: I've tried that approach, but it doesn't seem to be working. When I tap the button it indeed calls inputField.Select(), but at the same I cannot scroll anymore. And if I disable Raycast target inside this button I cannot click it anymore so it doesn't make sense.